# Go back in webview by pressing "back button"

Tags: android, webview

How can I go back one page while in webview? For example: I am on my app in activity and browsing pages in webview, but once I press back button it will exit the app or just goes back in activity instead of the page..

I have done my research and overriding onBackPressed function doesnt work.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Whole fragment code:

```
 public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {


    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://myapp.com");

    }


}
```

Any suggestions of how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed()` is method of Activity, not of a Fragment, so this code will never be invoked. If you want to do something on back press, your parent activity must let your fragment know about it - you must implement `onBackPressed()` in parent activity and in that method you should call fragments' method (or fire event on event bus, or use listeners, callback, whatever).

Also right method name is `onCreateView()`, not `onViewCreated()` - this one won't be called either.

Comment: Its on **onViewCreated** because **onCreateView**  `WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);` will be unreachable statement. And webview works just fine

Comment: Beg you pardon? You cannot name methods as you like and expect them to work. What `will be unreachable statement` means? Fragment must implement `onCreateView()` anyway, so maybe post your whole fragment (or at least all vital methods).

Comment: If I use `WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView);` in **onCreateView** it will be unreachable statement, but in **onCreateView** all works fine. How is that then? See my question, posted all code

Comment: You do this wrong. Your webview is part of you fragment, so you should be looking for `R.id.webView` just in the view you created in `onCreateView(), not in parent activity. Activity's `onBackPressed()` should not directly talk to your webview, but to your fragment instead, And your fragment should talk to WebView. Otherwise what's the point of breaking your code into smaller objects if they aren't decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

**Inside of the your OnCreateView:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

      webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(expertsUrl);

        return view;
    }


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Ok! In your MainActivity you will write it:

```
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
if(yourname_Fragment.webView!=null){
            if (yourname_Fragment.webView.canGoBack()) {
                yourname_Fragment.webView.goBack();
            }
}
        }
```

yourname_Fragmen.java= This is your nameFragment that content the Webview

webView= The name of your WebView (id)

Now. Inside of your Fragment  you have to declare static global variable

```
public static Webview webView;
```

NOTE: If you have more than one fragment you have to check if this instance is different of NULL;

And that's it! Good luck!

Comment: Like I said, it is a fragment onBackPressed() does not work

Comment: I didnt read! I changed.. @StuckBetweenTrees  Because You can do a reference to your laout with your view. I already modified it! Can you try?

Comment: Don;t really get it what you have done here.."Put it in your mainActivity or Fragment" wont work either or

Comment: Really! Suck! After my job I will create a project and I will try... if I find the solution I will tell you..

Comment: I mean its prob me who is noob here..but I have main activity which has 3 fragmens where you can swipe them left and right. In one of these fragments I have webview and that fragments code I have attached in the question..I just can seem to get it working

Comment: Yes I know I did exactly in a project it. I had 5 fragments and two of those were WebView and I didn't have problem! But I will check it @StuckBetweenTrees

Comment: It says cannot resolve symbol view and onBackPressed is never been used..I put them all in my fragment because putting them as you say, some in activity and some in fragment gives just errors all over the place

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Yes.! I found it. I had the same problem today! :D

Comment: I edited my answer @StuckBetweenTrees Its really work. Are you working with fragments rigth?